# Create a column based on changes between levels in another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to create a new column based off of factors present in another column. For example I have the following data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c("1","1","2","2"), Month = c("01", "02", "01", "02"), Percentile = c("P50", "P95", "P97", "P85"))
> df
  ID Month Percentile
1  1    01        P50
2  1    02        P95
3  2    01        P97
4  2    02        P85
```

I want to create a new column, PercentileChange to say that the for an individual ID, look at the first months percentile and compare it to the next months percentile and see if it increased or decreased and by how many levels so I would get an output like this:

```
> df2
  ID Month Percentile PercentileChange
1  1    01        P50               NA
2  1    02        P95               +4
3  2    01        P97               NA
4  2    02        P85               -3
```

These are the levels present in the Percentile column

```
df$Percentile <- factor(df$Percentile,levels=c("P01","P1","P3","P5","P10","P15","P25","P50","P75","P85","P90","P95","P97","P99","P999"))
```

**Edit: Adding longer df example:**

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","3","3","3"), Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "01", "02", "02", "03", "05"), Percentile = c("P50", "P95", "P97", "P85", "P01","P01", "P5","P5","P3"))
> df
  ID Month Percentile
1  1    01        P50
2  1    02        P95
3  1    03        P97
4  1    04        P85
5  2    01        P01
6  2    02        P01
7  3    02         P5
8  3    03         P5
9  3    05         P3


Output:
  ID Month Percentile PercentileChange
1  1    01        P50               NA
2  1    02        P95               +4
3  1    03        P97               +1
4  1    04        P85               +3
5  2    01        P01               NA
6  2    02        P01                0
7  3    02         P5               NA
8  3    03         P5                0
9  3    05         P3               -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` `ID` and get the distance between the indexes of the factor levels in the `Percentile` column:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(PercentileChange = levels(Percentile) %>%
         {match(Percentile, .) - match(lag(Percentile), .)})
```

#### Further explanation:

```
levels(Percentile) %>%
             {match(Percentile, .) - match(lag(Percentile), .)}
```

Is equivalent to

```
match(Percentile, levels(Percentile)) - match(lag(Percentile), levels(Percentile))
```

And, `match(Percentile, levels(Percentile))` will yied in which position on the `levels(Percentile)` vector the values on `Percentile` lie.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation! When I apply to my real data set I get the following error `Error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing PercentileChange = levels(Percentile) %>% .The error occurred in group 1: ID = 1. Caused by error in lag(): ! n must be a positive integer, not a character vector of length 15` I think this is due to the IDs having more than 2 rows, is there some way to incorporate the Month column in to solve this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your real data? Paste the output from `dput(df)` please

Comment: My data frame is over 500000 obs long with lots of identifying data, easiest for me to just add more to the example data frame I think – change made in original post

Comment: My solution is quite general, and it does work for the longer example also. My theory is that this error indicates that some other argument is being passed to `lag(Percentile)` (probably through the `%>%` pipe), making so that `Percentile` gets "pushed" onto the second argument, named `n`. `n` should be the number of positions to lag by, and when it receives `Percentile` (a character vector) this error gets trown. This can happen if something got altered when you transposed the code, maybe relating to the pipe, `{`, and `}` positions

Comment: Yep, your code 100% works, completely user error. The only other thing I added was `%>% arrange(ID,Month) %>% ` before `group_by` so the months were ordered as well. Thanks so much!